# Is there angular component or code to create a Material.io drawer?

Tags: angular, material-design, navigation-drawer, navbar, mat-sidenav

Material.io site have a good side navbar with **clickable** header items, **clickable** sub items and **progressbar at right side** from sub items.

[image]
[image]

Is there ready angular component or ready fragment of angular code to make the same side navbar? Didn’t anyone do this on angular?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The closest what you can get out of the box is this:
[link](https://material.angular.io/components/sidenav/overview)

You have to do the rest by yourself...
(worth checking the last example)